# Receber tamanho do vetor

Tags: vba

Gostaria de saber como faço para ter o tamanho do meu vetor no VBA.

Pesquisei algumas coisas mas não consegui localizar nada. Como eu posso recuperar esse valor?

Comment: `vetor.Length` não funciona?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, no caso do VBA, o vetor não é um objeto. Não há métodos ou atributos que você possa acessar para, por exemplo, obter o tamanho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O tamanho do array pode ser obtido utilizando a função **UBound**. Note, entretanto, que essa função não retorna o tamanho do vetor, mas o último índice acessível.

veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
Sub teste()
  Dim s(1) As String    
  s(0) = "L"
  s(1) = "B"
  MsgBox UBound(s)
End Sub
```

MsgBox UBound(s) irá mostrar 1 (o último índice acessível) e não 2 (o tamanho do vetor).

Portanto, para saber o tamanho, basta somar + 1 (MsgBox UBound(s) + 1)

Comment: Valeu Cantoni funcionou aqui obrigado!